# sockets close the client when the server is closed

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client

server slide:

```
    public void Hey()
    {
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        LingerOption lo = new LingerOption(false, 0);
        sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.Linger,lo);

        try
        {
            sck.Bind(Login.ip_ep);
            sck.Listen(100);
            Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
            byte[] buff = new byte[300000];



            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();


            read = accepted.Receive(buff, buff.Length, 0);
            m.Write(buff, 0, read);
            while (read > 0)
            {
                read = accepted.Receive(buff, buff.Length, 0);
                if (read != 0)
                    m.Write(buff, 0, read);


            }

            Bitmap p = new Bitmap(m, false);
            m.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = p;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            accepted.Dispose();
            accepted.Close();
            sck.Dispose();
            sck.Close();


        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Hey);
        t.Start();



    }
```

client slide :

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b as Image);
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, b.Size);
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pictureBox1.Image = b;
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                sck.Connect(Login.ip_ep);

                    MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
                    pictureBox1.Image.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


                    sck.Send(s.ToArray());
                    sck.Dispose();
                    sck.Close();



            }
            catch (Exception f) { 

            }



        }
```

I want to close the Client socket whenever I close the server is it possible to do that ? 
another thing after I close the Server and reopen it I get only usage of each socket address is permitted what is that ?

Comment: Does not closing the server socket raise an exception in the client, (which you are ignoring)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't ignore exceptions. You will get an IOException: 'connection reset' when you write to the server after it has closed its end of the connection. If you're reading, you will get -1 from read(), null from readLine(), or an EOFException from readXXX() for any other X.